# sp_rename in stored procedure does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

The 3 following statements work fine when executed consecutively but when I wrapped them in one stored procedure I am getting this error msg:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Invalid column name 'split'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   Invalid column name 'split'.

The procedure definition:

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[dsplit_SITEL_update]
as
begin
   set nocount on;

   IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns 
             WHERE [name] = N'split_' AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dsplit_SITEL$'))

       exec sp_rename @objname = N'dsplit_SITEL$.split_', 
                      @newname = 'split', 
                      @objtype = 'COLUMN';

   insert into dsplit_SITEL
      select 
          CONVERT(varchar(10), b.row_date, 120) + '_' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), b.split), 
          b.*
      from dsplit_SITEL a 
      right join dsplit_SITEL$ b ON a.pk = CONVERT(varchar(10), b.row_date, 120) + '_' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), b.split)
      where a.pk is null and b.row_date is not null;

    if OBJECT_ID('dsplit_SITEL$', 'U') is not null
       drop table dsplit_SITEL$;
END
```

What is going on here and how can I have the procedure work?

Comment: Maybe not the point, but why don't you just use the column with its non-modified name, if you're planning to drop the entire table by the time your procedure ends?

Comment: The thing is I use the dsplit_SITEL$ as temporary table just to update the main dsplit_SITEL. And the problem is that sometimes they send the table with incorrect column names with trailing underscore: 'split_' instead of 'split'

Comment: That shouldn't matter. The column names in the `SELECT` clause of an `INSERT...SELECT` aren't used for anything, and you're using `SELECT *` so either table should work.

Comment: Te OP is JOINing on `split` column.

Comment: I use [split] to make a primary key field: ...CONVERT(nvarchar(10), b.split)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is that at create time SQL Server tries to bind names to objects. If the table doesn't exists at the moment, that's fine (it's called deferred name resolution). However, if the table exists but the column doesn't, it will fail with the 'invalid column name' error.

You can work around this if you make the SQL dynamic, at least the part using the renamed column, something like this:

```
declare @s nvarchar(4000)
set @s = N'
    insert into dsplit_SITEL
    select 
        CONVERT(varchar(10), b.row_date, 120) + ''_'' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), b.split), 
        b.*
    from dsplit_SITEL a 
    right join dsplit_SITEL$ b ON a.pk = CONVERT(varchar(10), b.row_date, 120) + ''_'' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), b.split)
    where a.pk is null and b.row_date is not null;
'
exec (@s)
```

Comment: Thanks for comments Dean. Can you suggest such a dynamic SQL for this case?

Comment: Yes, this works. Although it still seems odd to me that the engine throws an error before executing the actual code which is correct in the end.